# On a property of complex exponentials

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, integration

Does there exist a simple smooth closed curve $\gamma:S^1\to \mathbb C$ such that
$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{\gamma(e^{it})} \, |\gamma'(e^{it} )|\,dt =0?$$

Comment: What about $\gamma(z)\equiv z$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis but this does not make sense since I am asking for $\gamma$ to be a closed contour. Here $S^1$ is the torus.

Comment: @Ali: Your notation is a bit confusing since the symbol $t$ would suggest a real parameter, but then your integration is over $S^1$. Similarly, $\gamma'(t)$ is easily interpreted for real $t$, but not for a complex $t$ when $\gamma$ is just smooth (not holomorphic).

Comment: Perhaps, I don't understand your notations/definitions. Usually, $S^1$ denotes the unit circle. In you comment, you say that $S^1$ is "the torus". Then  $S^1$ must be the **one-dimensional** "torus" (that is, the unit circle), in order for $\gamma$ to be a curve indeed. So, it seems that then the identity map of $S^1$ is a simple smooth closed curve (if anything is a simple smooth closed curve in your setting).

Comment: The integral is just supposed to be the integral of $e^z$ over a simple closed curve with respect to its lebesgue induced measure.

Comment: @ChristianRemling the derivative of $\gamma$ is simply the derivative of the real part plus i times the derivative of the imaginary part

Comment: @Ali : Your edited post (and what you said in comments) differs greatly from your original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the change of the variable $w=\gamma(t)$ your integral
becomes
$$\int_\gamma e^wds,$$
where $ds$ is the length element, $ds=\sqrt{dx^2+dy^2}$, and $\gamma$ is a Jordan curve of zero index about the origin. Now notice that on every vertical segment of length $2\pi k$, where $k$ is an integer,
this integral is zero. Now construct a simple closed curve, of zero index about the origin, consisting of 8 straight segments, 4 vertical and 4 horizontal. All vertical segments have length $2\pi k_j$
and all hosizontal segments lie on the lines $y=\pi/2+\pi k_j$, and the curve is symmetric with respect to complex conjugation. Such a curve is easy to draw, and the integral along it is 0. Indeed it is zero on each vertical segment,
while contributions from horizontal segments cancel.

Let me add how to make the curve smooth. We will slightly modify the original curve, keeping the vertical segments unchanged, so their contribution to
the integral is zero. We will also keep the symmetry
with respect to the complex conjugation, so that imaginary part of the integral will be 0.

First we choose the vertical segments $\mathrm{Re} z=x_k$ so that for some segments $\cos x_j<0$ and for
some other $\cos x_j>0$, so that the contribution to
the integral of some segments is positive and for other segments it is negative. Then, to make the curve smooth, we replace some small pieces of horizontal segments near the corners by pieces which make the curve smooth. Since the contribution of some of these pieces is negative and others positive, it is clear that the pieces can be chosen so that their contribution cancels.

Comment: The OP requested that the curve be smooth. Is your curve smooth?

Comment: It is piecewise smooth. But it is possible to round the corners, and keep integral zero.

Comment: I am wondering how this can be done: "to round the corners, and keep integral zero".

Comment: On the other hand, if the smoothness condition is disregarded, it is unclear to me why you need $8$ (rather than $4$) straight segments and why you need the curve to be of zero index.

Comment: @Josif Pinelis: you are right: 4 straight segments is enough. On how to round the corners, I will add to my ans.